# Minimum current for charging a battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, solar-cell, solar-charge-controller

Recently I bought a 12V 200Ah battery for my solar system with 500W 18v (27A) solar panels. I find a label on the battery which is notice that the minimum charging current is 10% of the battery capacity. 10% of 200Ah is 20A.

Max. current comes from my solar panels **in cloudy days** is less than 10A,

**So dose it means that the charging process totally stop in cloudy days or just become slow?**

I want to connect two batteries together in parallel (400 Ah), so the minimum current to charge them become 40A? (according to this battery label).

[Datasheet of battery](https://farberpower.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/SMF-BATTERIES1.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Strange writing on the battery. I would no worry about charging it with a low current. But how do you terminate the charge?

Comment: This is the recommended current value of what is written on your photo above. The current less than 10% requires more time to charge. But it is admissible. A current of more than 25% of capacity can heat the battery, which leads to a decrease in service life ..

Comment: On deleted question...Insufficient info. more likely feedback was disturbed by arc and recovery overshoot cause the generator  to go out of regulation from over field currents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charging will certainly not stop if you charge with a smaller current, it will just be slower.

The reason to specify the minimum charge current is not entirely clear and not specified in the document you linked to. I can think of at least two possibilities:

- This is the minimum current the battery is supposed to draw from a constant voltage charger, that is, a constant 13.8...14V source.
- This is the recommended minimum charge current which prevents acid stratification after a deep discharge.

Unless you can find which one it is, I suggest to avoid the situation where your charge current is always below the minimum value, especially if the battery will rarely reach full charge.

Comment: It looks like a SLA, so it's almost guaranteed to be sulfation prevention.